# Add element at the end of a Linked List in java

Tags: java, linked-list, addition

We started learning Lists in school but I don't really understand how they work. As homework we have to write a method add that adds an element at the end of the list. I don't know why, but when I add more nodes, the Lists only saves the first two. I want to know why and what should I change. This is the code (I am not allowed to change anything from the given code. I can only create new methods...)

```
public class HeadList {

    Entry head;

    public HeadList() {
        head = null;
    }

    /**
     * Appends a new element with value info to the end of this list
     * @param info value of the new element
     */
    public void add(int info) {
        //TODO

       Entry node = head;

        if (head != null) {
            if (node.next == null){
                node.next = new Entry(node, null, info);
            }
            else{
                Entry n = node.next;
                while(n != null){
                    n = n.next;
                }
                node = new Entry(node, null, info);
            }
        }
        else
            head = new Entry(null, null, info);

    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String out = "[";
        if (head != null) {
            out += head.elem;
            Entry tmp = head.next;
            while (tmp != null) {
                out = out + "," + tmp.elem;
                tmp = tmp.next;
            }
        }
        out += "]";
        return out;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HeadList l = new HeadList();
        l.add(6);
        l.add(7);
        l.add(8);
        l.add(9);
        System.out.println("empty list: " + l);
        // Test implementation

    }

    class Entry {

        Entry first;
        Entry next;
        int elem;

        public Entry(Entry first, Entry next, int elem) {
            this.first = first;
            this.next = next;
            this.elem = elem;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: The first time you call add(int info), head is null, and you enter by the else statement.  All the next calls, execute only the if.  And in the if, you have to search de last Entry objetc that has its 'next' field null.  I hope this could help you to find the right answer.

Comment: Also this is incorrect:   node = new Entry(node, null, info);  It should be  node = new Entry(head, null, info);

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints. They helped me understand the problem better. And I'll edit my question right away after I am done reading the dos and don'ts.

Answer (score 0):

change your add method to this:

```
public void add(int info) {

    Entry node = head;

    if (head != null) {
        if (node.next == null){
            node.next = new Entry(node, null, info);
        }
        else{
            Entry n = node.next;
            while(n != null){
                node =n;
                n = n.next;
            }
            Entry next = new Entry(node, null, info);
            node.setNext(next);

        }
    }
    else
        head = new Entry(null, null, info);

}
```

also update your Entry class:

```
    class Entry {

    Entry first;
    Entry next;
    int elem;

    public Entry(Entry first, Entry next, int elem) {
        this.first = first;
        this.next = next;
        this.elem = elem;
    }

    public void setNext(Entry next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

   }
```

Comment: I tested the code before submitting solution. it works.

Comment: While this may be the correct answer, it would be beneficial to clarify exactly what in the asker's code you changed.  Otherwise, this answer doesn't help.

Comment: in add method, after i found the last element, i save it to node , create new Entry (next which is last element now) and setNext field of before last element(node).